# Jsonp with jquery to build list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, jsonp

I have read many descriptions here and from other sources describing using jquery to get json and build a list. So, I have a super-simple html page with a ul on it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>        
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(getElementsInGroup);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="memberList">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two methods for getting members in main.js. The first uses getJson:

```
function getElementsInGroup() {
var url = 'http://108.250.12.12:8080/members?format=json&jsonp=?';
$.getJSON(url, null, function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data, function(index, element) {
      items.push("<li>" + element.text + "</li>");
      });
  $('#memberList').append( items.join('') );
  });
};
```

I can see in firebug that the call is fired and the results return:

```
[{"text": "Bob Jones", "id": 1}, {"text": "Mary Smith", "id": 2}]
```

However, the list does not display and neither do any errors. So I tried creating a version of the function that where I just put that hard-coded reult in:

```
function getElementsInGroup2() {
      var items = [];
      var data = [{"text": "Bob Jones", "id": 1}, {"text": "Mary Smith", "id": 2}];
      $.each(data, function(index, element) {
          items.push("<li>" + element.text + "</li>");
          });
      $('#memberList').append( items.join('') );
};
```

And this produces the list I am looking for. Is there anything you can see I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you getting when you console.log($('#memberList')) inside .getJSON?

Comment: I don't see anything. @raam86

Comment: Does anything change after the ajax call? anything appended to the dom?

Comment: The result that is returned is JSON, **not** JSONP. You can only use JSONP if the server supports it.

Comment: @felix That was it! One of our endpoints did not support jsonp. I fixed it and it works now. Thanks! Don't know how I missed it.

Comment: Well, I'm glad I could "help" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually that the route that I was using did not support jsonp. I modified the route and all is good now. Thank you @Felix.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the result from JSON post, so here you need to use for loop to bind your list. Use like
for(i=0;i<=data.length;i++){
   items.push('

' + data[i].text + '

');
}